# After IE 10 compatibility changes,Client is unable to add only one user in assigned to field in SharePoint task list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

`We were facing browser compatibity issuee in  SharePoint 2010 environmnet while adding people through people picker. We made compatibility changes and after that everyone can use people picker properly except one client.

Client is able to add everyone in assigned to field in SharePoint Task list except one. When enter user name and click on people picker, it's throwing correlation id error. But can add other users.

When I and my colleague tried adding that user, we can do it successfully. This means there is no problem with that user domain account. 
ULS logs showing this

> System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not
>   defined.    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToXmlQualifiedName(String
>   value, Boolean decodeName)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read1_Object(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read2_DictionaryEntry(Boolean
>   checkType)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read3_ArrayOfDictionaryEntry()   60c20f4f-05c0-4d92-b035-ea0252cf072b
>   04/09/2014 11:42:54.08    w3wp.exe (0x3830)
>     0x41C8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (POST://xyz:80/xyz/_layouts/Picker.aspx?MultiSelect=False&CustomProperty=User%3B%3B15%3B%3B%3BFalse&DialogTitle=Select%20People&DialogImage=%2F%5Flayouts%2Fimages%2Fppeople%2Egif&PickerDialogType=Microsoft%2ESharePoint%2EWebControls%2EPeoplePickerDialog%2C%20Microsoft%2ESharePoint%2C%20Version%3D14%2E0%2E0%2E0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D71e9bce111e9429c&ForceClaims=False&DisableClaims=False&EnabledClaimProviders=&EntitySeparator=%3B%EF%BC%9B%EF%B9%94%EF%B8%94%E2%8D%AE%E2%81%8F%E1%8D%A4%D8%9B&DefaultSearch=)).
>   Execution Time=59.1060456007677   60c20f4f-05c0-4d92-b035-ea0252cf072b

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to upgrade SharePoint 2010 to [SP2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687453) which provides full support for IE10.

People picker problems abound prior to SP2 (even with compatibility mode).

Comment: Thanks Phil. We are migrating to SharePoint 2013 in few weeks so dont know upgrading SP2010 to sp2 will be acceptable by all. What will you suggest for adding compatibility tag in pickerdialog master. will it be useful?

Comment: @Phil Greer: Thanks so much for you reminder. Mine is SP2010 and IE 11. This error is gone when I changed to Compatibility View.